# Binding Verification Email to disable button property

Tags: javafx, binding

I would like to disable button CREATE ACCOUNT all fields aren't fill correctly.

I was configured mandatory verification :

```
    this.buttonRegister.setDisable(true);   
    BooleanBinding disableBinding = this.mailBox.textProperty().isEmpty()
            .or(this.loginField.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(this.passwordField.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(this.passwordConfirmField.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(this.passwordField.textProperty().isNotEqualTo(this.passwordConfirmField.textProperty()));

    this.buttonRegister.disableProperty().bind(disableBinding);
```

I would like also add email verification. I fave a function. But I cannot add this to . my disableBinding.

```
private Boolean emalValidation() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(this.mailBox.getText());              
    if(m.find() && m.group().equals(this.mailBox.getText())) {
        return Boolean.TRUE ;
    } else {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

How  must I construct a boolean property for this verification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `or` method multiple times to create the `disableBinding`, you could also use [`Bindings.createBooleanBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createBooleanBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) with a custom `Callable<Boolean>` checking, whether the inputs are valid or not and add all the properties that the result depends on as dependencies:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+");

BooleanBinding disableBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
        this.loginField.getText().isEmpty()
         || this.passwordField.getText().isEmpty()
         || !this.passwordConfirmField.getText().equals(passwordField.getText())
         || !pattern.matcher(this.mailBox.getText()).matches(),
    this.mailBox.textProperty(),
    this.loginField.textProperty(),
    this.passwordField.textProperty(),
    this.passwordConfirmField.textProperty());
```

Note that I removed 2 of the conditions, since 2 equal strings are empty iff one of them is empty and the pattern does not match for the empty string.

---

Note that you could of course only create a `BooleanBinding` for the `emalValidation()` check, but I do not recommend that:

```
...
.or(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(this::emalValidation,
                                  this.mailBox.textProperty()).not());
```

Comment: thank you a lot. Both of resolutions works fine.   Could you also explain me  why the firs method is better ??  And give me the good tutorial, for using it??  I was  looging for . tutorial to BooleanBildings but I did;nt find any good explainations.  thx a lot one more time :)

Comment: @VANILKA It's just creating a binding using the `Callable` to compute the value. This binding is invalidated every time one of the dependencies is invalidated. That's pretty much all there is to know about these kind of methods... The first method is better since you do not need multiple listeners per dependency to calculate the result and do not need to create a additional `BooleanBinding` object. Furthermore you can control the order of the checks. E.g. in case you have an empty `loginField`, there is no need to check the pattern, which is more expensive than the other checks.